# Recyclerview not showing kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, listitem

`Recyclerview` is not showing on screen just show white background.

Is it there any mistake? Please tell me, thanks.

```
Adapter
class NeedsAdapter(var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NeedsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NeedsAdapter.ViewHolder {
        var view = View.inflate(parent.context, R.layout.needs_item, null)
        var parms = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        view.layoutParams = parms
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 10;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }

}
```

Fragment

```
class NeedsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var adapter: NeedsAdapter
    private lateinit var layout: View
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_needs, container, false)
        adapter = NeedsAdapter(this!!.activity!!)
        recyclerView = layout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context!!, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        return view
    }

}
```

I want to show just items on `recyclerview`.

Comment: The above code is used for initialization of Recyclerview with configuration of adapter. I don't see any code related to working with data and design. Please post the code for Data and Design.

Comment: post your  XML files here. Activity and Item

Comment: actually you inflate the layout but returns a null view. change "return view" to "return layout" and set the LayoutManager to the recyclerview. And you do not need to call notifyDataSetChanged(

Answer (score 6):

You have missed setting layout manager

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)
```

Comment: This will generate null pointer exception.