# recyclerView (still) not showing items on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I know that there are plenty of similiar posts about similar issues as mine, I even followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273294/recyclerview-in-fragment-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060279/recyclerview-not-showing-kotlin) and other posts as well (I won't list every single post here though) and tried different things out, but I still can't make my `recyclerview` show anything on my `Fragment`.

I write an app mostly for learning purposes - something similar to [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0), just to get sense about how things work together. If you like to see the project, (at least what I've done so far), you can do this [here](https://github.com/BWappsandmore/doItAgain).

I just want to show items on `recyclerview`. Currently, nothing from the `recyclerview` is shown in the `Fragment` a white background only :(.

I don't even get **any** errors sort of "No adapter attached; skipping layout" or "No LayoutManager attached; skipping layout". And I am sure this could be a really small issue, so could you please explain me what am I missing or doing wrong.

Thank you so much for your efforts.

Here is what I do:

The `Adapter` code:

```
class ActivitiesAdapter internal constructor(
    context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ActivitiesAdapter.ActivitiesViewHolder>() {
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var activities = emptyList<DoItAgainEntity>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ActivitiesViewHolder {
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
        return ActivitiesViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ActivitiesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = activities[position]
        holder.activityItemView.text = current.engagement
    }

    internal fun setActivities(activities: List<DoItAgainEntity>) {
        this.activities = activities
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = activities.size

    inner class ActivitiesViewHolder(itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {
        val activityItemView: TextView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }
}
```

The `Fragment` code:

```
class ShowDBEntriesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: ShowDBEntriesViewModel
    private lateinit var layout: View
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: ActivitiesAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_dbentries_fragment, container, false)
        adapter = ActivitiesAdapter(context!!)
        recyclerView = layout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                context!!,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            )
        )
        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context!!, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        return layout
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ShowDBEntriesViewModel::class.java)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = (activity as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            val fragment = InsertNewEngagementFragment()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_newEngagement, fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    }

}
```

The `xml` code from `recyclerview_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/activity_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You didn't set any data to your adapter

Comment: Have you insert any data in your database?

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman Thank you for your help. I've populated data in my database.

`suspend fun populateDatabase(doItAgainDao: DoItAgainDao) {
            doItAgainDao.deleteAll()

            var engagement = DoItAgainEntity(1, "play guitar", 100)
            doItAgainDao.insert(engagement)
            engagement = DoItAgainEntity(2, "make breakfast", 2)
            doItAgainDao.insert(engagement)
            engagement = DoItAgainEntity(2, "go out with friends", 20)
            doItAgainDao.insert(engagement)
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer of this issue. I don't OWN this code. This code was written from a genious with huge heart (and also a friend of mine) who understands how things work and writes beautiful code. It's a great honor of mine to learn from you, bro - thank you so much for your ultimate kindness and god-like Android knowledge you have! Keep it up like this.

And here it is - the right way of doing things:

The `Adapter` code:

```
class ActivitiesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ActivitiesViewHolder>() {

    private var activities = emptyList<DoItAgainEntity>()

    internal fun setActivities(activities: List<DoItAgainEntity>) {
        this.activities = activities
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ActivitiesViewHolder =
        ActivitiesViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.recyclerview_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ActivitiesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(activities[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = activities.size
}

class ActivitiesViewHolder(
    override val containerView: View
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), LayoutContainer {

    fun bind(vo: DoItAgainEntity) {
        itemView.textView.text = vo.engagement
    }
}
```

The `Fragment` code:

```
class ShowDBEntriesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: ShowDBEntriesViewModel
    private lateinit var activitiesAdapter: ActivitiesAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_dbentries_fragment, container, false)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ShowDBEntriesViewModel::class.java)

        activitiesAdapter = ActivitiesAdapter()
        recyclerview.apply {
            addItemDecoration(
                DividerItemDecoration(
                    context!!,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
                )
            )
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = activitiesAdapter
        }

        // for testing purposes. could be deleted easily
        activitiesAdapter.setActivities(
            listOf(
                DoItAgainEntity(1, "play guitar", 100),
                DoItAgainEntity(2, "make breakfast", 2),
                DoItAgainEntity(2, "go out with friends", 20)
            )
        )

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = (activity as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            val fragment = InsertNewEngagementFragment()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_newEngagement, fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    }

}
```

The `xml` code from `recyclerview_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/activity_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `setActivities()`.

Your code will look like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_dbentries_fragment, container, false)
        adapter = ActivitiesAdapter(context!!)
        recyclerView = layout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                context!!,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            )
        )
        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context!!, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        // Create activities variable
        adapter.setActivities(activities)
        return layout
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But this doesn't work - the `activities` variable is on this place unresolved.

Comment: You need to create the variable (with some itens) and pass it to your adapter, your adapter is empty.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I was expecting that the adapter will show the prepolulated data. If you would like to take a look on the project on GitHub, you will see that I prepopulate the database with some dummy data. At the moment, the adapter doesn't show this data, but I will try your advice out too.

Comment: You prepopulate just on DB, but you have to load it on recycler view, in your activity you got do something like that: `val data =  doItAgainDao.getAll() ` then `adapter.setActivities(data)`. You need to get data from your DB, then set on your recycler view.

Comment: thanks for your response. This was more or less the reason why entries were not shown on the recyclerView. Finally I found a working solution for this problem that I will share it and also accept it. But really thank you so much for pointing out to the right direction. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In `recyclerview_item.xml`

Change 
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
to 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

The item layout is probably taking entire layout space.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, but this didn't change anything.